# ArcGIS Pro feature class anchor points lost when shared online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

I have a simple ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3 project which features a few point items on a map. The feature class is displayed using markers and the anchor point in the Y dimension was set to -50% in order to assure that the lower tip of the marker was always pointing to the feature on the map no matter the zoom level.

This works well in ArcGIS Pro desktop, however, when the feature class is shared as a Web layer in ArcGIS Online, the anchor configuration is lost. All other characteristics of the feature class are kept (type of marker, color, etc.)

The following screen capture from ArcGIS Pro shows exactly to location of the feature just above the small lake.
[image]

The same feature class in ArcGIS Online shows a slightly different location because the anchor point of the marker is the center instead of being the lower tip of the marker.
[image]

The question is how is it possible to included the marker anchor points when publishing layers from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online ?